# An error appears "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'", none of the tips helped

Tags: python

**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website =    'https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/'  
result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')




box = soup.find('div', class_='tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last')


title = box.find('div').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')

print(title)
```

**

Other answers didn't help
I looked at a lot of similar questions, none helped

Comment: `box.find('div')` is returning `None` which means it isn't finding a `div`.

Comment: By going to the website, vieweing its source and searching for "tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last", the first div I find is `<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"></div>`. Which is an empty div; you won't find another div inside it.

Comment: the error is gone, but then just an empty result